# Calculating probability for collision

Tags: probability, exponential-function, pi

[Image Taken from Birthday Paradox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvZpp.png)

Taken from [Birthday Paradox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjficaVn6fQAhXBQY8KHVbNCasQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.sun.ac.za%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F10%2Fmmile_writeup.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFn7KKxP14m1tcbtgKg3bTB0yAflg&sig2=OAny2jiH1Vp9rkLIAFIuKQ&bvm=bv.138493631,d.c2I)

Why when k$<<$m, we can replace (1-$\frac{i}{m}$) with $e^\frac{i}{m}$? I do not understand the calculation steps in the article starting from the seconds step. Can someone explain to me or point out some of the keywords or topics I should explore to find out?

Comment: Hint: taylor serie for $e^x$ to the first order is $1+x $ when $x\rightarrow 0$...if you replace $x$ with $\frac{i}{m}$ you'll get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the taylor serie of $e^x$ (here $x=-\frac{i}{m}$) to the first order:

\begin{equation}
e^{-\frac{i}{m}}=1-\frac{i}{m} 
\end{equation}

with $i\ll m$

Comment: Thank you MattG88, I did not realize. Thanks for the hint. However, I still don't understand how $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{e^\frac{-i}{m}}$ = $e^{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{i}{m}}$. Can give some hint? I am really new to $\prod$ and $e$

Comment: Because $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$...in that computation you have $k$ factors not only two as in my example but it works anyway.